# package.json and bower.json in CoffeeScript?

Tags: json, coffeescript, npm, bower, gulp

I would like to write my `package.json` and `bower.json` in CoffeeScript.

I'm using Gulp, but i'm very novice in writing Gulp tasks.

How do i make NPM and Bower consume CoffeeScript configs?

PS I failed to find how to override the path to Bower's and NPM's configs, so it seems that i'll have to save compiled JSON files to disk. :( Is there a way to avoid that and pipe JSONs to `npm` and `bower` commands without disk reading/writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npm & Bower don't support [cson](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cson). Related issues:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2412
- https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1541

Comment: I said i use Gulp in my project, so it should be totally possible to leverage `cson` or `coffeeson` or even vanilla `coffee-script`. The question is implementation details.

Comment: How do you install modules (for example gulp) for your project if package.json is missing? :)

Comment: Something like this: `npm install -g gulp; gulp npm-install`.

Comment: You need local install of gulp too. But anyway, I would't go that way.